# Duplicate entry error code in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, duplicates, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1062

My lecturer has given me a document with raw data in and I have to create tables and implement it into MySQL.

Background: The raw data has multiple transactions from companies. Some transactions are from the same company so the same `COMPANYID` comes up often.

The lecturer told us to insert the raw data into a table titled `RAW` to store everything. Then we have to insert data into our smaller tables from that `RAW` table.

**ISSUE:**
My issue is when I’m trying to create my table `COMPANY`, I obviously want to include the `COMPANYID`.

But when I use the code

```
Insert into COMPANY
Select distinct COMPANYID, COMPANYNAME, NumberofDivisions
From RAW;
```

I get the duplicate error because obviously in the `RAW` table, the same `COMPANYID` comes up multiple times for each transaction!

How can I only have the `COMPANYID` once in the `COMPANY` table?

Answer (score 0):

Try `insert ignore` instead of `insert` which would continue inserting records till the end of file even though duplicate record error.

```
Insert ignore into COMPANY
Select distinct COMPANYID, COMPANYNAME, NumberofDivisions
From RAW;
```